# Get radius to fetch markers in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native

I just would like to ask for example I get the latitude and longitude point in the MapView so how can I get radius distance from that point to the bound of my MapView?

The library I am using is this one: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps

Comment: Please could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to know the physical distance on the map, or the pixel distance from the edge of the control?

Comment: I would like to get distance in meter from the center point to the top left corner of the whole mapview on the screen

Comment: I will have a look at this properly later, but you should be able to assign a handler to the region changed event. Then when you centre your map on the marker you will receive an updated region. I expect that you can work out the distance you require from that, although I may be wrong.

Comment: This should be an issue on the mentioned library